# How to find a crticial edge in a flow network?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

The complete question is as follows:

> An edge of a flow network is called critical if decreasing the
> capacity of this edge results in a decrease in the maximum flow. Give
> an efficient algorithm that finds a critical edge in a network.

I believe some variation of Ford-Fulkerson would have to be used over here, however I am not too sure. Also I am a little confused by the wording of the question. What does efficient mean? In linear time i.e. $O(|V| + |E|)$?

Comment: We  require you to credit the source of all material originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) the (maximum) flow $f$ between two vertices $s$ and $t$ in the network is equal to the overall weight of the edges in a minimum $s$-$t$-cut $C$.

The means that it suffices to find a minimum $s$-$t$-cut $C$ and return any edge $e \in C$ (decreasing the capacity $e$ reduces the weight of the minimum cut and hence the flow from $s$ to $t$).

A way to find $C$ using again the relation with the maximum flow is as follows: find a maximum flow from $s$ to $t$ (using the algorithm of your choice) and let $S$ be the set of saturated edges, i.e., edges such that the flow across them matches their capacity. Choose $C$ as the set of all edges $(u,v)$ such that $u$ is reachable from $s$ and $v$ can reach $t$ in $G-S$.

Comment: Can we use the residual graph to get $C$?

Comment: The saturated edges of $G$ are exactly those that are not in the residual graph $G'$. Still, you cannot simply pick $C$ as all edges in $G-G'$ since this set might be too big (think for example of a graph $G$ consisting of a single path from $s$ to $t$ where all edges have the same capacity).  However the set of vertices reachable from $s$ in $G-S$ is exactly the set of vertices reachable from $s$ in the residual graph $G'$. Similarly, the set of vertices that can reach $t$ in $G-S$ are exactly those that can reach $t$ in $G'$, so you can simply perform two visits on $G'$ to discover $C$.

Comment: I believe this finds the so called "bottleneck edges" -- edges if we increase their flows it would increase the max flow.  In the single path with equal flow edge example, every edge is a critical edge.